# How to generate Dynamic Suffix for Base64 encoded file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file, base64, href

I've been searching for quite a long time for this but still have not found any answer. What I'm trying to do is quite simple, generate the base64 suffix based on file extension string in order to use this in an anchor tag element to download it through href. This is my code so far:

```
getFileSufix(fileExt) {
    switch (fileExt) {
        case 'pdf':
            return 'data:application/pdf;base64,';
        case 'doc':
            return 'data:application/msword;base64,';
        case 'docx':
            return 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,';
        case 'jpg':
            return 'data:image/jpg;base64,';
        case 'png':
            return 'data:image/png;base64,';
    }
}
```

The real question is what should I put next to the empty return statments. Or if there is an easier way to achieve it I would be more than glad. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you simply searching for MIME types? Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

Comment: By the way: in the case `jpg`, the MIME type is PNG, which does not make sense. Secondly, you don't need the `break` statements, as the `return` statement will instantly stop execution when returning a value.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Seabyte, i've also changed the code as you suggested.